# newline/carriage return in FBConnect post on wall

Tags: ios

May be this question has been asked before but I could not find any solutions for the problem.
Using FBConnect for an iOS application [older sdk], I need to post on the user's wall a formaatted [html text]. I've tried using html tags in the post message but the message is missing these html tags. Is there a way to insert new line/carriage return characters like `<br>`,`'\n'` etc in the posted message?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use html to format the messages you want to publish to the users stream. However according to a discussion here http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=45931 you can enter new lines into the message by typing \n

Comment: Seems using '\n' inside the NSString does not work. Can you suggest an example NSString.